# Pacemaker cluster service can't start properly Couldn't mount filesystem

Tags: rhel, mysql, cluster, pacemaker, drbd

I have 3 nodes MySQL cluster on RHEL 7.5 with DRBD, Pacemaker and after start cluster getting following error. How can I overcome ?

```
[root@db1 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: mysql_cluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: db2 (version 1.1.18-11.el7-2b07d5c5a9) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Sun May 19 01:41:05 2019
Last change: Sat May 18 19:14:37 2019 by hacluster via crmd on db2

2 nodes configured
5 resources configured

Online: [ db1 db2 ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: MySQLClone01 [mysql_data01]
     Masters: [ db2 ]
     Slaves: [ db1 ]
 mysql_fs01     (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Stopped
 mysql_service01        (ocf::heartbeat:mysql): Stopped
 mysql_VIP01    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Stopped

Failed Actions:
* mysql_fs01_start_0 on db1 'unknown error' (1): call=22, status=complete, exitreason='Couldn't mount filesystem /dev/drbd100 on /var/lib/mysql',
    last-rc-change='Sun May 19 01:22:26 2019', queued=0ms, exec=115ms
* mysql_fs01_start_0 on db2 'unknown error' (1): call=28, status=complete, exitreason='Couldn't mount filesystem /dev/drbd100 on /var/lib/mysql',
    last-rc-change='Sun May 19 01:22:27 2019', queued=0ms, exec=198ms


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Comment: pcs has a debug start utility that helps you find the issue, try this command:
`pcs resource debug-start mysql_fs01`
If you suspect this was a temporary error you could also try `crm_resource -P` to get rid of the failed actions and try the mount again